# Anchor link don't work in dreamweaver CC 2015

Tags: html, dreamweaver

This is the part code, where the anchor doesn't seem to work, When i click **Move P,L,C**, **pick&place** or **Approach & depart** in the Lessons section, it won't move to the section i want it to go.

```
<div class="bb-item" id="item2">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="scroller">
            <h2>Lessons</h2>
            <p><a href="#item3" class="button" >Move P, L, C</a></p>
            <p> <a href="#item4" class="button">Pick and place</a> </p>
            <p><a href="#item5" class="button">Approach and depart</a></p>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bb-item" id="item3">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="scroller">
            <a name="item3"></a>
            <h2> Move P, L, C</h2>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript

```js
(function() {

 var event = jQuery.event,

  //helper that finds handlers by type and calls back a function, this is basically handle
  // events - the events object
  // types - an array of event types to look for
  // callback(type, handlerFunc, selector) - a callback
  // selector - an optional selector to filter with, if there, matches by selector
  //     if null, matches anything, otherwise, matches with no selector
  findHelper = function( events, types, callback, selector ) {
   var t, type, typeHandlers, all, h, handle, 
    namespaces, namespace,
    match;
   for ( t = 0; t < types.length; t++ ) {
    type = types[t];
    all = type.indexOf(".") < 0;
    if (!all ) {
     namespaces = type.split(".");
     type = namespaces.shift();
     namespace = new RegExp("(^|\\.)" + namespaces.slice(0).sort().join("\\.(?:.*\\.)?") + "(\\.|$)");
    }
    typeHandlers = (events[type] || []).slice(0);

    for ( h = 0; h < typeHandlers.length; h++ ) {
     handle = typeHandlers[h];
     
     match = (all || namespace.test(handle.namespace));
     
     if(match){
      if(selector){
       if (handle.selector === selector  ) {
        callback(type, handle.origHandler || handle.handler);
       }
      } else if (selector === null){
       callback(type, handle.origHandler || handle.handler, handle.selector);
      }
      else if (!handle.selector ) {
       callback(type, handle.origHandler || handle.handler);
       
      } 
     }
     
     
    }
   }
  };

 /**
  * Finds event handlers of a given type on an element.
  * @param {HTMLElement} el
  * @param {Array} types an array of event names
  * @param {String} [selector] optional selector
  * @return {Array} an array of event handlers
  */
 event.find = function( el, types, selector ) {
  var events = ( $._data(el) || {} ).events,
   handlers = [],
   t, liver, live;

  if (!events ) {
   return handlers;
  }
  findHelper(events, types, function( type, handler ) {
   handlers.push(handler);
  }, selector);
  return handlers;
 };
 /**
  * Finds all events.  Group by selector.
  * @param {HTMLElement} el the element
  * @param {Array} types event types
  */
 event.findBySelector = function( el, types ) {
  var events = $._data(el).events,
   selectors = {},
   //adds a handler for a given selector and event
   add = function( selector, event, handler ) {
    var select = selectors[selector] || (selectors[selector] = {}),
     events = select[event] || (select[event] = []);
    events.push(handler);
   };

  if (!events ) {
   return selectors;
  }
  //first check live:
  /*$.each(events.live || [], function( i, live ) {
   if ( $.inArray(live.origType, types) !== -1 ) {
    add(live.selector, live.origType, live.origHandler || live.handler);
   }
  });*/
  //then check straight binds
  findHelper(events, types, function( type, handler, selector ) {
   add(selector || "", type, handler);
  }, null);

  return selectors;
 };
 event.supportTouch = "ontouchend" in document;
 
 $.fn.respondsTo = function( events ) {
  if (!this.length ) {
   return false;
  } else {
   //add default ?
   return event.find(this[0], $.isArray(events) ? events : [events]).length > 0;
  }
 };
 $.fn.triggerHandled = function( event, data ) {
  event = (typeof event == "string" ? $.Event(event) : event);
  this.trigger(event, data);
  return event.handled;
 };
 /**
  * Only attaches one event handler for all types ...
  * @param {Array} types llist of types that will delegate here
  * @param {Object} startingEvent the first event to start listening to
  * @param {Object} onFirst a function to call 
  */
 event.setupHelper = function( types, startingEvent, onFirst ) {
  if (!onFirst ) {
   onFirst = startingEvent;
   startingEvent = null;
  }
  var add = function( handleObj ) {

   var bySelector, selector = handleObj.selector || "";
   if ( selector ) {
    bySelector = event.find(this, types, selector);
    if (!bySelector.length ) {
     $(this).delegate(selector, startingEvent, onFirst);
    }
   }
   else {
    //var bySelector = event.find(this, types, selector);
    if (!event.find(this, types, selector).length ) {
     event.add(this, startingEvent, onFirst, {
      selector: selector,
      delegate: this
     });
    }

   }

  },
   remove = function( handleObj ) {
    var bySelector, selector = handleObj.selector || "";
    if ( selector ) {
     bySelector = event.find(this, types, selector);
     if (!bySelector.length ) {
      $(this).undelegate(selector, startingEvent, onFirst);
     }
    }
    else {
     if (!event.find(this, types, selector).length ) {
      event.remove(this, startingEvent, onFirst, {
       selector: selector,
       delegate: this
      });
     }
    }
   };
  $.each(types, function() {
   event.special[this] = {
    add: add,
    remove: remove,
    setup: function() {},
    teardown: function() {}
   };
  });
 };
})(jQuery);
(function($){
var isPhantom = /Phantom/.test(navigator.userAgent),
 supportTouch = !isPhantom && "ontouchend" in document,
 scrollEvent = "touchmove scroll",
 // Use touch events or map it to mouse events
 touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
 touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
 touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove",
 data = function(event){
  var d = event.originalEvent.touches ?
   event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
   event;
  return {
   time: (new Date).getTime(),
   coords: [ d.pageX, d.pageY ],
   origin: $( event.target )
  };
 };

/**
 * @add jQuery.event.swipe
 */
var swipe = $.event.swipe = {
 /**
  * @attribute delay
  * Delay is the upper limit of time the swipe motion can take in milliseconds.  This defaults to 500.
  * 
  * A user must perform the swipe motion in this much time.
  */
 delay : 500,
 /**
  * @attribute max
  * The maximum distance the pointer must travel in pixels.  The default is 75 pixels.
  */
 max : 75,
 /**
  * @attribute min
  * The minimum distance the pointer must travel in pixels.  The default is 30 pixels.
  */
 min : 30
};

$.event.setupHelper( [

/**
 * @hide
 * @attribute swipe
 */
"swipe",
/**
 * @hide
 * @attribute swipeleft
 */
'swipeleft',
/**
 * @hide
 * @attribute swiperight
 */
'swiperight',
/**
 * @hide
 * @attribute swipeup
 */
'swipeup',
/**
 * @hide
 * @attribute swipedown
 */
'swipedown'], touchStartEvent, function(ev){
 var
  // update with data when the event was started
  start = data(ev),
  stop,
  delegate = ev.delegateTarget || ev.currentTarget,
  selector = ev.handleObj.selector,
  entered = this;
 
 function moveHandler(event){
  if ( !start ) {
   return;
  }
  // update stop with the data from the current event
  stop = data(event);

  // prevent scrolling
  if ( Math.abs( start.coords[0] - stop.coords[0] ) > 10 ) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 };

 // Attach to the touch move events
 $(document.documentElement).bind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler)
  .one(touchStopEvent, function(event){
   $(this).unbind( touchMoveEvent, moveHandler);
   // if start and stop contain data figure out if we have a swipe event
   if ( start && stop ) {
    // calculate the distance between start and stop data
    var deltaX = Math.abs(start.coords[0] - stop.coords[0]),
     deltaY = Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]),
     distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY);

    // check if the delay and distance are matched
    if ( stop.time - start.time < swipe.delay && distance >= swipe.min ) {
     var events = ['swipe'];
     // check if we moved horizontally
     if( deltaX >= swipe.min && deltaY < swipe.min) {
      // based on the x coordinate check if we moved left or right
      events.push( start.coords[0] > stop.coords[0] ? "swipeleft" : "swiperight" );
     } else
     // check if we moved vertically
     if(deltaY >= swipe.min && deltaX < swipe.min){
      // based on the y coordinate check if we moved up or down
      events.push( start.coords[1] < stop.coords[1] ? "swipedown" : "swipeup" );
     }

     // trigger swipe events on this guy
     $.each($.event.find(delegate, events, selector), function(){
      this.call(entered, ev, {start : start, end: stop})
     })
    
    }
   }
   // reset start and stop
   start = stop = undefined;
  })
});

})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated ans

```html
<div class="bb-item" id="item2">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scroller">
      <h2>Lessons</h2>
      <p><a href="#item3" class="button">Move P, L, C</a></p>
      <p> <a href="#item4" class="button">Pick and place</a> </p>
      <p><a href="#item5" class="button">Approach and depart</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="bb-item" id="item3">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scroller">
          <h2> Move P, L, C</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="bb-item" id="item4">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scroller">
          <h2>Pick and place</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="bb-item" id="item5">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scroller">
          <h2>Approach and depart</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i followed your steps, but it's still not working, or is the live preview not working?

Comment: I've replace your codes with mine. it's still not working, is it because of the javascript? I'm still new to coding,sorry!

Comment: I've updated my question with the js code. I'm actually doing a single page website with tabbed contents, if a tab is click, it should only show the specific tab.